# viewport "Solid" mode object mirroring culling issue

Tags: mirror

In 2.90.0 the 3d viewport "Solid" mode some mirrored objects aren't culled. No issue in "Texture" mode. I've checked normals with no change to the problem. Other objects that are mirrored don't have an issue.

thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: Did you check *Object Properties > Viewport Display > In Front*?

Comment: @HISEROD, Yes Object Properties > Viewport Display > In Front was the problem, thanks. However when I first view "In Front" it was NOT checked. So I checked it then unchecked it and BAM fixed it. Again thanks for the help.